# ML packages in R: caret v e1071

Tags: r

I've looked and surprisingly have not found too much discussion on the relative strengths of the `caret` and `e1071` package.  From my understanding, these packages perform many of the same ML algorithms.  With that in mind, I'm interested in what those practitioners who have experience with both think these packages relative strengths and weaknesses are.  What do you think about readability of code, ease of coding, methods, speed, etc...

In particular I'm interested in multi-class SVM

Comment: If you want to compare packages with similar functionality, compare `caret` and `mlr`. It's my impression that `mlr` is a second-generation answer that's been influenced by Python's SciKit-Learn. For whatever reason, I'veI never had much luck with `caret`, but haven't gotten to try `mlr`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that `caret` and `e1071` serve difference purposes. First lets discuss `caret`, its closest competitor is the `mlr` package. Both are meta packages that allow to optimize models across parameters. Take for example a problem where you are not sure whether you would want to use Lasso or Ridge to create a model. As explained [here](https://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/22067_48fad02fb1a944e9a8fb1d56c55119ef.html#ridge-regression-and-lasso) `caret` allows to choose the optimal lambda based on different type of cross validations.

The `e1071` package instead is a bag of functions developed by the TU Wien. It is probably one of the most popular packages for support vector machines which are used by `caret`. But its goal is very different than `caret`, it implements learning algorithms and other functions whereas `caret` seeks to find the best parameter in learning models.

Answer (score 1):

It depends.

All most all the professors (in my univ) would show students examples in `e1071`. The somewhat weird name `e1071` is from a course name.

However, if you have hand-on experience on industry or kaggle, you would find the preprocessing functions of `caret` is quiet useful. Specify what you want by several arguments. You get normalization, fill NAs, cross validation etc. Extremely easy. No headache at all.

If time permits, play both.